# add new row to dataset.tables[i] and update database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have two sql servers(one of them is in my web server: server A, another one is local: server B)

I use the code bellow to copy data on a table in SQL SERVER A to another table in SQL SERVER B :
(different servers & different databases.. **the two tables are same in columns**)

ON for server A

OFF for server B

```
        string strsql = "SELECT * FROM **serverA_table**";
        ONda = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql, ONcon);
        ONds = new DataSet();
        ONda.Fill(ONds, "serverA_table");


        strsql = "SELECT * FROM serverB_table";
        OFFda = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql, OFFcon);
        OFFds = new DataSet();
        OFFda.Fill(OFFds, "serverB_table");

        DataRow[] newRow = ONds.Tables["serverA_table"].Select();

        DataTable dtTarget = new DataTable();
        dtTarget = OFFds.Tables["serverB_table"].Clone();

        foreach (DataRow temp in newRow)
        {
            dtTarget.ImportRow(temp);
        }



        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(OFFda);
        OFFda.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
        OFFda.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
        OFFda.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();
        OFFda.Update(OFFds.Tables["serverB_table"]);
```

But NOTHING happens and no row is added(imported) to my serverB_table !

please help me with this code or let me know a new way to do this action !

thanks in advance.

Comment: I cant see anywhere in your code where you have opened a connection?

Comment: suppose that the connection is opened and everything is working without error.

Comment: lol, then in that case your code would be working and this post wouldn't exist ;-) You need to step through your code, line by line to find the fault what have you tried so far?

Comment: creating new connection and connecting to database is so obvious and simple that I didn't think it's necessary to write them ! no error doesn't mean that your code do exactly what you expect! I want to know what's wrong with my code.. anyway.. thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `DataRow.SetAdded` before importing the row. Try the following:

```
string strsql = "SELECT * FROM ServerATable";

using (ONcon = new SqlConnection(conString))
using (ONda = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql, ONcon))
{
    ONcon.Open();
    ONds = new DataSet();
    ONda.Fill(ONds, "serverA_table");
}

strsql = "SELECT * FROM ServerBTable";

using (OFFcon = new SqlConnection(conString))
using (OFFda = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql, OFFcon))
{
    OFFcon.Open();
    OFFds = new DataSet();
    OFFda.Fill(OFFds, "serverB_table");

    DataRow[] newRow = ONds.Tables["serverA_table"].Select();

    foreach (DataRow temp in newRow)
    {
        temp.SetAdded();
        OFFds.Tables["serverB_table"].ImportRow(temp);
    }

    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(OFFda);
    OFFda.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
    OFFda.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
    OFFda.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();
    OFFda.Update(OFFds.Tables["serverB_table"]);
}
```

Comment: WOW! amazing :) although I didn't understand the role of .SetAdded() method, my problem solved clearly. thanks a lot.